# Paul’s relationship with Barnabas

Tags: acts, paul, context, barnabas

Acts 15:39a

> And the contention was so sharp between them [Paul & Barnabas], that
> they departed asunder one from the other

“Paul did not forgive Barnabas but rejected his companionship?” The theologian Roger Olsen made this comment on his blog post. That piqued my interest in knowing more about Paul and Barnabas' relationship.

Comment: Can you provide a link to Olsen's remark?

Comment: https://www.patheos.com/blogs/rogereolson/2021/06/must-a-christian-forgive-unconditionally/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=BRSS&utm_campaign=Evangelical&utm_content=259

Answer (score 1):

Paul and Barnabas had a falling out as Paul was preparing for his 2nd missionary journey (approx. AD 49):

> 36 And some days after Paul said unto Barnabas, Let us go again and
> visit our brethren in every city where we have preached the word of
> the Lord, and see how they do.
>
> 37 And Barnabas determined to take with them John, whose surname was
> Mark.
>
> 38 But Paul thought not good to take him with them, who departed from
> them from Pamphylia, and went not with them to the work.
>
> 39 And the contention was so sharp between them, that they departed
> asunder one from the other: and so Barnabas took Mark, and sailed unto
> Cyprus;
>
> 40 And Paul chose Silas, and departed, being recommended by the
> brethren unto the grace of God. (Acts 15:36-40)

Barnabas wanted to take his relative (nephew or cousin) John Mark with them, but Paul did not wish for Mark to come--John Mark had abandoned their missionary endeavors (for unknown reasons) during Paul's first missionary journey, see Acts 13:13.

Paul apparently made amends eventually with Mark, who is mentioned positively in later Pauline epistles, e.g. Colossians 4:10, 2 Timothy 4:11, which reads:

> Take Mark, and bring him with thee: for he is profitable to me for the ministry

Whatever Paul's concerns with Mark, they appear to have been resolved by the time of Paul's Roman imprisonments (circa 60-62 & 64-Paul's death).

The positive mention of Barnabas in 1 Cor. 9 suggests that Paul & Barnabas eventually worked out their differences as well. Their relationship had strong roots considering the many labors they performed together in their missionary service (see Acts 13-15).

**Conclusion**

Even faithful disciples of the Lord have their struggles, and the command to forgive doesn't go away or become simple when people choose to follow Christ.

Comment: I have assumed here that the captivity epistles were written during Paul's first Roman imprisonment, except for 2 Timothy, written during his second Roman imprisonment. This chronology is not unusual, but is not unanimously held. If anyone has concerns with this approach and would like to discuss, I'm always up for a round of Pauline chronology!

Answer (score 1):

As is well-known, Barnabas is not mention again in Acts after chapter 15 where Paul and Barnabas had their sharp disagreement over Mark, at the beginning of what should have been their second missionary journey.

However, both Barnabas and Mark, whatever their differences with Paul, still had a dealings with Paul.  The book of 1 Corinthians was written from Ephesus (1 Cor 16:8), presumably while he was there on his third missionary journey.

Paul mentions Barnabas in 1 Cor 9:6 as one of the unpaid/unsalaried Apostles without a trace rancor.

Similarly, the book of Galatians was written by Paul also mentions Barnabas in Gal 2:1 positively.

The incident in Acts 15:35-39 is a salutary incident - Paul could not work with Barnabas, but that does not imply that he held any grudge against either Barnabas or Mark (2 Tim 4:11).  Paul was supremely practical, forthright and decisive.  He also appears to be (given some time as most of us need) willing to allow people to grow as Mark obviously did.

Barnabas saw potential in Mark that Paul, if he saw it, was unwilling to wait for the training and maturity to develop.  Later, when both Mark had matured, Paul worked with him.